# Syntax highlighting in the Dokuwiki editor?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, dokuwiki

Is there any way to have syntax highlighting in the "editor" of dokuwiki?

By this I mean to have syntax highlighting in the actual editing window (in real time) just like using a text editor.

I have never seen anything like this but I was wondering if this is possible. Since I'm inputting a lot of LaTeX math thing into my dokuwiki, it would be great if it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:aceeditor - I never tried it myself, but it seems to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it and let you know if it works well.

Comment: Oh that was not what I wanted. I actually wanted LaTeX syntax highlighting in the editing page, not dokuwiki syntax highlighting. Thanks anyway!